# Run Same Testcafe tests with different URLs per environment

Tags: automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am working on a TestCafe proof of concept.  I have a few tests working in one test environment.  I need a way to run the same tests in up to 3 different test environments that have different URLs.  Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to add custom options on the testcafe command-line like for example : `--env=uat`.

Use `minimist` to read all custom options that you have added to the TestCafe command-line and export a config object like this:

```
import * as minimist from 'minimist';

const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));

// get the options --env=xxx --user=yyy from the command line
export const config = {
  env: args.env,
  user: args.user,
};
```

Then import that `config` object wherever you need it in the test code.

see [How do I work with configuration files and environment variables?](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#how-do-i-work-with-configuration-files-and-environment-variables) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[In v1.20.0](https://testcafe.io/404002/release-notes/framework/2022-7-18-testcafe-v1-20-0-released#global-starting-url) and later, TestCafe offers a way to specify the `baseUrl` in the test run setup:

- [CLI](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--base-url)
- Program API [`runner.run({baseUrl})`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402655/reference/testcafe-api/runner/run#baseurl)
- [Config file](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#baseurl)

You can use this approach along with environment variables or custom command line arguments to determine what url should be assigned to the `baseUrl` option.
Alternatively, you can have a different configuration file for each test run setup and switch between these files using the [`--config-file` option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--config-file-path).